# Ruby Minitest assert_equal fails

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a gemfile with the following:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'cucumber'
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.10', '>= 5.10.3'
gem 'minitest-focus'
gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.1.9'
gem 'rspec'
...
```

A Cucumber .env file with this to load and require the gems:

```
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require
```

And a Ruby file with the following:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative './../../../../RubyProjects/mksta-common/common'

class VerifyApi < MiniTest::Test

  include Common

  def initialize(has_authorization)
    @has_authorization = has_authorization
  end

  def test_id_correct
    assert_equal(20, 20)
  end
end
```

I am receiving this error when attempting to do that assert:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

In Assertions.rb:

```
def assert_equal exp, act, msg = nil
      msg = message(msg, E) { diff exp, act }
      result = assert exp == act, msg

      if exp.nil? then
        if Minitest::VERSION =~ /^6/ then
          refute_nil exp, "Use assert_nil if expecting nil."
        else
          where = Minitest.filter_backtrace(caller).first
          where = where.split(/:in /, 2).first # clean up noise

          warn "DEPRECATED: Use assert_nil if expecting nil from #{where}. This will fail in Minitest 6."
        end
      end

      result
    end

def assert test, msg = nil
      self.assertions += 1
      unless test then
        msg ||= "Expected #{mu_pp test} to be truthy."
        msg = msg.call if Proc === msg
        raise Minitest::Assertion, msg
      end
      true
    end
```

Error occurs at the line: "self.assertions += 1" so i am not sure where "assertions" is not being set..

I am wondering if my require process is incorrect, or if i am missing a requirement. Or perhaps Cucumber / Rspec is getting in the way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere you are calling `+` for `nil`...it's not in the code posted so it must be in the code you didn't post

Comment: Check the full stack-trace for where this error occurs, then figure out which variable is `nil` that shouldn't be. The good news is you caught this in a test and not after deploying your application.

Comment: @SimpleLime I have edited my question with the code where the error occurs, within MiniTest.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is when you initialize VerifyApi, you did not initialize MiniTest::Test. So the self.assertions is nil.
To solve this problem, you just need to add one more line in the initialize function

```
super(name)
```

Of course, you need add one parameter in the function.